# Salesforce is not creating lead and it doesn't return Lead Id

Tags: android, google-chrome, salesforce, http-post, salesforce-service-cloud

Hi guys i have been using **salesforce Rest Api** for logging and now i wanted to **create lead** using **access token** that is returned to me by the Login call. But when i try to create the lead using the access token it isn't created and the response i get doesn't contain a **Lead id**.

I have been stuck on this for days and after a lot of Googling i couldn't find an answer.

**I want to implement this functionality in android but for now i am using Google chrome Plugin Advance Rest Client for Testing.**

**Create Lead URL-->** https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead

**Header -->**

```
Authorization: OAuth 00Di0000000Y4be!AR8AQHCnNzqTM1tItXuwTRdXfRmn7JbZlneSA3pMjmrw.5aZqz0JecaTj2coEXHbEi61iQEhHWg0lTc0BZ0k4U_1BccJvFaZ
```

**Payload or Body -->**

```
{"Phone":"789452",    

"Company":"Test Company",   

"Fax":"1238356"
,"LastName":"Micheal"

}
```

**Content-Type:** `application/json`

**I am using a post Request.
And the Response i am getting is**

```
    {
objectDescribe: {
name: "Lead"
label: "Lead"
keyPrefix: "00Q"
custom: false
labelPlural: "Leads"
layoutable: true
activateable: false
urls: {
sobject: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead"
describe: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/describe"
rowTemplate: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/{ID}"
}-
searchable: true
deprecatedAndHidden: false
createable: true
updateable: true
deletable: true
customSetting: false
feedEnabled: true
mergeable: true
queryable: true
replicateable: true
retrieveable: true
undeletable: true
triggerable: true
}-
recentItems: [8]
0:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Luna, Wilredo"
}-
1:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Rannga, Lite"
}-
2:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Sith, Aro"
}-
3:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Smith, Aberen"
}-
4:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "RANAHAN, MICHAEL"
}-
5:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "RABADI, RAED"
}-
6:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "A., Christopher"
}-
7:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Ratnayake, Sam"
}-
-
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue.I am posting the answer so that it may help those of you who are facing the same problem

What i was doing was that i was sending a login request as described in this [screenshot](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/2131/fsso.png). And i was getting the following response.

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Di00000Y4EAC/005i0000000kAAA",
    "issued_at":"13756912686",
    "instance_url":"https://company.my.salesforce.com",
    "signature":"UAcaAbSj7vClbc/yAURGkT/7Hkjq6sllhcGvASs=",
 "access_token":"00Di0000000Y4befdjBiSvJ7RfW1s1fmUsLCf6UAQCgtmD.biS7T5rSOxyvtniyLeLN"}
```

I just changed the **creating lead Url** from

https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead

to

**Format:**
instance_url+/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/

**Actual Url:**
https://company.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/

Now everything works.The problem was that i had to concatenate the **instance_url** with the **lead Url**. I dont think i can create lead unless i know the instance to which API calls should be sent.

As mentioned in the [Salesforce Rest API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/)

**instance_url: Identifies the Salesforce instance to which API calls should be sent**